# Android: ViewHolder в CustomAdapter для неодинаковых вьюх

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пользоваться ViewHolder'ом, когда заранее неизвестно как будет выглядеть лэйаут  итема?

[image]

Сейчас список выводится так. Но из-за отсутствия кеширования и из-за динамического построения каждого итема, при прокрутке список жутко лагает, даже на Nexus5, не  говоря уже о раздолбаном LG P970, на которых тестируется приложение.
Может быть есть какое-то рациональное решение? Собственное кеширование можно конечно написать, но это повлечет только дополнительный геморрой в сопровождении и понимании кода.

Comment: оффтопом очень полезная статья: [Performance optimization ][1]
  [1]: http://optimizationtricks.blogspot.in/2014/01/tricks-to-boost-performance-of-list-view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во первых: небольшой оффтоп: [Using lists in Android (ListView)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

во вторых: в tag можно поместить несколько значений, например несколько разных holder и view

```
public void setTag(int key, final Object tag)
```

то есть можно сделать пару констант `int TYPE, HOLDER_1, HOLDER_2, VIEW_1, VIEW_2;` и через них работать.

так же в tag'е можно хранить несколько view в каждой из которых будет свой holder

в третьих: не вижу проблем в создании кеша, нужно хранить

```
List<Pair<ViewType1,ViewType2>> cache;
//или ещё лучше
List<Map<Key,View>> cache;
```

позиции соответственно совпадают в data и cache.

p.s. на мой взгляд третий вариант самый оптимальный, так как в нём кеширование отделено от view и holder, то можно использовать много разных view, каждая со своим holder'ом. И в будущем будет легче оптимизировать и\или добавлять view...

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat - что-то у меня не сходится всё равно. 
Нашел проблему, которую не решает последний вариант с кешем, а именно этот лист вью обновляется по сокету и количество полей неизвестно и бесконечно (в разумных приделах, но что оно несчетно заранее это точно), потому под каждый итем заранее неизвестного формата может множество лайаутов. Я подумываю над вариантом - ExpandedList, где в качестве ParentItema будет выступать заголовок и время, а при нажатии будет налету генерироваться оставшаяся часть итема. Что скажете по поводу такой идеи?

Comment: тут смотря чего вам надо...

если я правильно понял то вам надо 

1.иметь несколько разделов в виде списка discussion, bugs, web etc... (список 0)
2.внутри каждого раздела иметь свой список означающий конкретную тему. (список 1)
3.внутри каждого пункта (список 1) отображать переписку (список 2)

если да то вам нужно или делать вложенные списки (у каждого свой кеш) или использовать ExpandableListView он должен подойти.

но я бы (список 0)(если там до 5 значений) сделал бы во вкладках с одним общим хедерем на который выводил бы кол. сообщений и их тип, ибо листать то что на скрине явно не удобн